# How to link my controller and values from the user?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I am new to practicing CakePHP, I want to get value from the webuser and my controller will search that value from the DB. I am just wondering how I insert my $_post value add it to following code?

```
class DataviewsController extends AppController {

public  $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function customer($id = null) {

    $this->loadModel('Customer','Stock');
    if (!$this->Customer->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid customer'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Customer.' . $this->Customer->primaryKey => $id));
    // Send the customer to the view
    $this->set('customer', $this->Customer->find('first', $options));
    $this->set('_serialize',array('customer'));

}
```

Comment: `$this->loadModel('Customer','Stock');` Where did you get that from. Check the documentation. It can only load on model at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can access post data in `$this->request->data` and get data in `$this->request->query`. As for your second question, I'm not sure what you are asking when it refers to the code you posted.

Comment: how to embed  the user entered value into my controller?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do with cakephp request handler object

here is very good example to create form and taking user data input and search from particular table. from that you can have very good idea how to implement in your application

just go throw [this link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/calin/2008/09/18/search-feature-to-cakephp-blog-example) Or [this one for cakephp 2.0](http://mrphp.com.au/blog/search-forms-cakephp#.UeoGH9JHKGc) and let me know if you need any more help